# reference to Cantor's intersection theorem in complete metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The Cantor's intersection theorem in the formulation of metric spaces says the following. Assume $A_{n}$ is a sequence of nested and closed subsets in a complete metric space.
Assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{diam}(A_{n})= 0$. Then $\cap_{n\in N} A_{n}$ is a singleton.

I am looking for a reference to the above theorem in some books on topology. I can't find a reference so quickly. May anyone suggest a reference?

Comment: Rather the diameter tends to 0.

Answer (score 2):

It's Theorem 4.3.9. in Engelking's *General Topology* (2nd ed.)

Also Lemma 7.3 (p 295) in Munkres' Topology (first edition), or Lemma 48.3 (p 297) in the second edition.

Answer (score 1):

"Introduction to Mathematical Analysis" by Steven A. Douglass proves this assuming the archimedean property of the reals.